# Obtain column names as vector in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to merge two data tables both have common column names. See below for my script. But I need to obtain the column names using a code but not manually enter like below.

Basically, I need to create a vector of column names for each data table.

```
 setkeyv(Tab_1, c("State","County_ID","Year")) 
  setkeyv(Tab_2, c("State","County_ID","Year")) 
  sub_Merge <- merge(Tab_1, Tab_2, all.x = TRUE)
```

For example something like this below,

```
  setkeyv(Tab_1, as.vector(colnames(Tab_1)) 
  setkeyv(Tab_2, as.vector(colnames(Tab_2)) 
  sub_Merge <- merge(Tab_1, Tab_2, all.x = TRUE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are your input and your expected output? To me you're looking for a join `Tab_1[Tab_2]` but I'm not sure to understand the question. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Apart from unbalanced parentheses, I'm not sure what you don't like about your existing code..? Fyi, `setkey(DT)` will do the same thing as `setkeyv(DT, names(DT))`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, it's pretty concise:

```
dt1[dt2, on = names(dt1)[names(dt1) %in% names(dt2)]]
```

`data.table` uses the `dt[i,j,by]` structure. Putting another data.table in the `i` slot asks to join it to the data.table in the `dt` position. In a join, you can add an `on=` statement to specify which columns to base the join on, if any keyed columns already present in the two data.tables aren't suitable for us as such. In the code above, `names(dt1)[names(dt1) %in% names(dt2)]` returns a list of columns that are found in both `dt1` and `dt2`, and feeds them into the `on=` clause. The idea of doing it this way, is that you can calculate shared column names on-the-fly, and don't have to write each one out.

This depends on having no duplicate values in `dt1`, and wanting to join on ALL shared columns in `dt1` and `dt2`.

I used this mock data:

```
dt1 <-
  data.table(
    a = LETTERS[1:10],
    b = letters[1:10],
    c = runif(10),
    d = runif(10)
  )
dt2 <-
  data.table(
    a = LETTERS[1:10],
    b = letters[1:10],
    e = runif(10),
    f = runif(10)
  )
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.